# Magento overloading a controller

Tags: class, magento, controller, overloading, router

I know there are a lot of examples out there for this issue and i think i read all of them, at least I feel so, a little bit confused :-) I think first of all i need basic conzept respectively a better appreciation of how is the best way to change the whole customer frontend dashboard and extend it with additional methods. I stuck a litte bit with this, maybe this is the wrong way, maybe not, hopefully you can help me finding the right way.

All needed files are located in:

**app/code/local/Company/Customer/etc/config.xml**

**app/code/local/Company/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php**

**app/code/local/Company/Customer/controllers/IndexController.php**

Atm I play with these path's:

**domain.com/customer/**

overwritten by:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>    
       <customer>
          <use>standard</use>
          <args>
             <module>Company_Customer</module>
             <frontName>customer</frontName>
          </args>
       </customer>
   </routers>
</frontend>
```

the above code is working, the overloading class is executed with the following function:

`function indexAction();`

and the path: **domain.com/customer/** or **domain.com/customer/index/** is functional.

So far, so good. But now I also need all the other path's and their functionality, e.g.
the **domain.com/customer/account/** path, normally executed and routed to the following path:

**app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php**

and here's the crux, is it possible to load the AccountController by execute or load them in the
IndexController.php class with a new method e.g. `function accountAction();` and stop Magento routing
to the above core path? Or is it better to do this the way I did by rewrite the magento router to my own module, to:

**app/code/local/Company/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php**

Maybe there are some other ways but my router isn't working:

```
<frontend>
   <routers>
      <customer_account>
      <use>standard</use>
      <args>
         <module>Company_Customer_Account</module>
         <frontName>customer_account</frontName>
      </args>
      </customer_account>
   </routers>
</frontend>
```

**EDIT:**

This is the from the error.log:

```
2011-07-25T10:36:46+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Mage/Customer/AccountController.php' for inclusion (include_path='/html/magento/app/code/local:/html/magento/app/code/community:/html/magento/app/code/core:/html/magento/lib:.:/usr/local/php/lib/php:/usr/local/php/lib/php/PEAR')  in /html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

I think this means that the router works but the file isn't found, right?!

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

**--------------------------------------------**

**----------------UPDATE----------------**

**--------------------------------------------**

Thanks for your reply. I allready tried the alternative rewrite in the global section before:

```
<rewrite>
   <Company_Customer_Account>
      <from><![CDATA[#^/customer/account/#]]></from>
      <to>/customer/account/</to>
    </Company_Customer_Account>
</rewrite>
```

and with your code:

```
<rewrite>
    <Company_Customer_Account>
      <from>/customer/account/index/</from>
      <to>/customer/account/index/</to>
   </Company_Customer_Account>
</rewrite>
```

both don't work, what i'm missing?

Here's the AccountController.php

```
<?php

//require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';

class Extension_Modul_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController {

    # Overloaded indexAction
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "executed";
        parent::indexAction();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't properly redirected to the original file... as the error states that it could not find `mage/customer/accountcontroller.php` but you wanted to load `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php` .. make sure that you redirected to the needed one

Comment: @kvijayhari Yeah but I don't want to redirect to the original file, all i want to do is to include my own controller, extending the original one, located in `app/code/local/Company/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php`. As you said the file couldn't found in `mage/customer/accountcontroller.php`, thats right because there is no folder **mage** in my module directory. But what i've to do, to get the right one?

Comment: how do you know that it is not working? it might be replacing the previous call by itself, so you do not see the difference. I think the problem is with the frontname it needs to be <frontName>customer</frontName> and there should be one frontname for one module btw. Plus you need AccountController.php with indexAction().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your front name : 'customer_account' needs to be as before 'customer' in the second example.

When you do domain.com/customer/ it automatically refers to IndexController -> indexAction();

In order to get domain.com/customer/account it can be done similarly and account here refers not to accountAction but AccountController.

The path system is usually like : Module/SomeController/someAction.

Alternatively you could add in your config global tag, sth like:

```
<rewrite><module_control_action><from>/module/control/action/</from><to>/mymodule/somecontrol/someaction/</to></module_control_action></rewrite>
```

Comment: if I change the `<frontName>customer_account</frontName>` to `<frontName>customer</frontName>` I think the router calls my allready existing controller in **Company/Customer/controllers/IndexController.php**, isn't there a way to run these two controllers parallel?

Comment: it calls the same module controllers but if you call it like domain.com/customer/account then it goes to or looks for the AccountController, indexAction.

Comment: The simple understanding you should stick to is : yourdomain.com/your-frontname/your-controller/your-action/any-param/any-param-value... and you can have multiple controllers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If I understand you right you mean: I just have to define a rewrite for the customer modul once? And if something, in this case the AccountController, is needed the router looks at first in my extension dir for the controller?

Comment: I've added the AccountController.php above

Comment: Thanks to Nasaralla and kvijayhari for bringing me nearer to this specific workflow of the zend engine. I think to understand how magento works, is to understand how the zend engine works. For those who have the same problem I've found a guide to overwrite the AccountController: [http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/how-to-extend-magento-core-controller/](http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/how-to-extend-magento-core-controller/)